# sound design for a quiet room

Tags: sound-design, quiet, room-tone

I need to design a couple of "room sounds" for our game ..
thing is that they're quiet since there's no one inside

for now I'm approaching this by

- having a room tone
- some occasional tiny sounds (little creaks etc..)

and it works..

but I still think there are some pieces missing.. so I was wondering if there are more approaches/ideas/suggestions to make these empty rooms sound more natural and organic..

any input welcome!

Answer (score 3):

Depends on the context of the game. Is there stuff going on outside the room, ie traffic, people, distant gunshots, dogs barking down the street, birds singing etc - some slightly muffled sound from these could be an option. Weather from outside, so wind, rain, and you can go for more creaks if it's windy. Clocks if there are any, buzzing lights, sound from radios or anything else in the environment. And you could always speak to the designer and see if they want to put one in for it to add to the atmosphere. Then you could add some subtle character to the room in the way of low drones or just audible air-drone chords which will become part of the room tone. Depends on music also.

Sometimes quiet is good too!

Comment: hey Mark. thanks for the insights. here's about the room itself. outside ambience is already set, music also etc.. and with no characters inside..no objects etc...just the room.. its character.. also that gives information about the size of the space around you..which is obviously crucial.. based on your thoughts I'm already there by using a custom "tone" made by either real recordings (basically resulting in a broad band noise) or subtle synth drones layered on top.. but still I feel that something else, a tiny detail maybe? is missing .. but maybe not as well. still researching.. but thanks!